# Twitter widget leaking memory on backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, twitter, coffeescript

I'm building a website using backbone and coffeScript, when i change from one section (innerpage) to another i replace the view rendered on the layout for the new one and call a close method on the old one. Everything seems to work fine, excep that to render the widget again on the home view, i need to call `twttr.widgets.load()` , and its creating a new widget everytime, but it seems the old ones are being retained, it doesn't matter if i remove the view or the iframe node, or make the container element empty. I've tried detaching the widget before removing the view, store it on a variable and use it to place the widget when the home view is called again, without the need to call the load method, but the iframe element is the only thing that is being kept in the variable (even though before removing the view it has everything on it), i've tried cloning the node, using the iframe contents, everything has failed so far. I can't seem to find a method to unload the twitter widget in the twttr obj, so i'm ending up with a nasty memory leak, it adds up to 3mb everytime it loads the home view, so this is not an option, specially for mobile, i can end up with 100mb being allocated to the ghost widgets.

```
root = window ? global

root.Backbone.View::close = ()->
  @remove()


class Otalvaro.Views.BaseContent extends Backbone.View

  initialize: ->
    @model.bind('sync', @render, this)
```

Here is my home view( In this version i'm trying to save the iframe contents, the normal version, does not check for inMemory closes the view with @remove() and removes the iframe directly)

**EDIT Note** : Removing the view wasn't working here, since on every new instanciation, the widget will create a new iframe (the widget id is even increased), so i'm trying to keep only the homeview on memory, since is better having 1 iframe in memory than 30 ghost iframes.

```
class Otalvaro.Views.Home extends Otalvaro.Views.BaseContent
  template: root.template('homeTemplate')

  initialize: ->
    super
    @inMemory = no

  closeTwitterWidget: ->
   $('iframe').unbind().remove()

  close: =>
    @$el = @$el.clone()
    @el = @$el[0]
    @iframe = @$el.find('iframe').contents()
    @inMemory = yes

  render: (callback)->
    if(@inMemory)
      console.log '@iframe', @iframe
    else
      console.log 'not in memory, doing normal rendering'
      if _.isEmpty(@model.toJSON())
        console.log 'model is empty, fetching it now'
        @model.fetch()
      else
        console.log 'model fetched, now rendering'
        @$el.html( @template(@model.toJSON()) )
        # With out the delay, the widget won't load everytime
        _.delay( ->
            console.log 'firing twttr.widgets.load()'
            root.twttr.widgets.load() # <- Guilty of all charges
        , 630)
        if callback? then callback(@el)

    this
```

This is part of the code of the layoutView, wich renders the views on route change:

```
class Otalvaro.Views.MainLayOut extends Backbone.View
  el: '#mainContent'

  closeOldViews: ->
    if @oldViews?
      for view in @oldViews
        console.log 'view to be closed', view
        view.close()

  ###
  # Takes an array containing one or more view instance as argument, adds a fadeOut fx to hide the current content
  # then it renders each view instance from the array and extracts its node element (el) and pushes it into an array
  # that is later (after the fadeIn completes) added as the html content of the layoutView
  ###
  show: (views)->
    @fadeOut()
    delay = 500 
    viewNodes = []

    for view in views
      node =  view.render().el
      viewNodes.push(node)

    _.delay(
      _.bind ->
        @closeOldViews()
        @$el.html(viewNodes)
        @fadeIn()
        @oldViews = views
   , this
delay)
```

Router Handler for home, using an already instanciated view, (also tried instanciating the home view on route change, but didn't help)

```
 home:->
    @mainLayout.show([@homeView])
    null
```

**Edit: Added ->Home Template**

```
<script id="homeTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <blockquote id="homeQuote">
        <p>Some Quote</p>
        <footer>Catalina Otalvaro</footer>
    </blockquote>
    <div class="twitterFeed fadeIn">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/kataotalvaro" data-widget-id="481647155510140928" class="twitter-timeline">Tweets by @kataotalvaro</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

I've read this couple of topics on the tiwtter developers forum, but they got no replies and i'm not very experienced with this, so if anybody outthere has any advice on how should i solve this , i really appreciate it, thanks for taking your time in reading my question :)

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/30128
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5957

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue, by storing the widget (`<div>` inside the widget iframe) on a property of my view, to get the widget is not as straightforward as it is to store any node from your document, and the storing must be made before the iframe container (main container) is empty or the iframe will be empty too. Now the main issue on this path, was to reappend the widget to the view, but i found out is not possible (or it seems that way) to add html content to an iframe that is not currently on the DOM, since that was my case because the iframe is actually just in the template of the view, i decided to attach the widget to a div, then all i needed was to take the iframe styling and add it to my main style (with some modifications), now when i rerender my home view is taking the elment from memory and there is no memory leak, i get around 6mb tops when navigating and never goes up, using the widget.load() it went as high as 50mbs. I don't think this is the ideal solution, its actually a hack, twitter should provide a way to unload the widget not just the load method. I hope this helps if somebody is on the same spot. Thanks @glortho for taking your time to answer =)

**Here is the modified home view**

```
class Otalvaro.Views.Home extends Otalvaro.Views.BaseContent
  template: root.template('homeTemplate')

  initialize: ->
    super
    @inMemory = no
    @memoryRender = no

  close: =>
    unless @inMemory
      @$iframe = $( $('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('body').html() )
      @inMemory = yes

  render: (callback)->
    unless @memoryRender
      if(@inMemory)
        @$el.find('.twitterFeed').html(@$iframe)
        @memoryRender = yes
      else
        console.log 'not in memory, doing normal rendering'
        if _.isEmpty(@model.toJSON())
          console.log 'model is empty, fetching it now'
          @model.fetch()
        else
          console.log 'model fetched, now rendering'
          @$el.html( @template(@model.toJSON()) )
          _.delay( ->
              console.log 'firing twttr.widgets.load()'
              root.twttr.widgets.load()
          , 630)
          if callback? then callback(@el)

    this
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `close` method in `Otalvaro.Views.Home` is overriding the base `close` method, which means that every time you close that home view, you're not actually removing the view and, further, you're cloning the element:

```
@$el = @$el.clone();
```

It could be that the `closeTwitterWidget` would help with some of that by removing the iframe, but I don't see where that's being called.

Try changing the `close` method in your home view to just `@remove()` and see how it goes.

Also, is the Twitter widget definitely loading inside the element for your home view?

Comment: Yah, maybe i explained wrong, initially i was using the @remove() and calling the widget.load() again, but it didn't work, so i override the close method to instead of actually closing the view, keep it on memory to append it again, but when i reatach @$el it shows everything but the contents of the iframe. And yes the widget.load() is being called if not in memory

Comment: I see `root.twttr.widgets.load()` being called, but what tells this widget to append to the home view? Is it in the `homeTemplate`?

Comment: Nopes, its handled by the twitter widget code. There is a link on the template, when calling widgets.load() it finds it and it replaces it with the iframe, i'll edit my question to add the template.

Comment: Hmmm. `@remove()` really should do want you want. rather than doing the `clone` try just `$el.hide()` inside your `close` method, and then `$el.show()` in `render` after testing positive for `inMemory`.

Comment: Might be an option, but when any other route is fired it replace the layout content, maybe i could do and append after the homeview but it doesn't feel clean, but gotta try. I'm checking right now the option of saving the iframe contents and placing it again, but i figure out that it seems to be impossible to append content to an iframe if is not in the dom, and taking out of the dom (detaching it) removes it contents but not the element itself :S